# Passing decimal values from dataTable to dataFrame fails

Tags: c#, dataframe, datatable, r.net

I have created this code sample to pass an object of type c# DataTable to R.Net dataFrame.

```
public static DataFrame ConvertDataTableToRDataFrame(DataTable tab)
{
    REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
    REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
    double?[,] stringData = new double?[tab.Rows.Count, tab.Columns.Count];
    DataFrame df = engine.Evaluate("df=NULL").AsDataFrame();
    int irow = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in tab.Rows)
    {
        NumericVector x = engine.Evaluate("x=NULL").AsNumeric();
        int icol = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn col in tab.Columns)
        {
            if (row.Field<double?>(col) == null)
            {
                x = engine.Evaluate("x=c(x, NA) ").AsNumeric();
            }
            else { x = engine.Evaluate("x=c(x, " + row.Field<double?>(col) + ") ").AsNumeric(); }
            icol++;
        }
        df = engine.Evaluate("df= as.data.frame(rbind(df,x)) ").AsDataFrame();
        irow++;
    }
    return (df);
}
```

Everything seems to work fine untill i try to inspect the content of the dataframe. I found that values like `1.2355` turn in the dataframe to `12355`. For some unknown reason it doesn't recognize `.` as decimal separator.

Comment: if you are trying to evaluate `decimal` values as numeric why are you not evaluating the specific row `.AsDecimal`...?

Comment: I'll bet your locale uses `,` as the decimal separator, so when you use string concatenation in `"x=c(x, " + row.Field<double?>(col) + ") "` to generate an expression, `1,2355` is generated instead of `1.2344`.  Use String.Format and specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` explicitly. A far better option though would be to avoid conversionst to string

Comment: @MethodMan i have [link](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/documentation) as reference, and they mention that the evaluation for double vectors is AsNumeric. I tried putting AsDouble or AsDecimal instead and it says "has no definition for ..."

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the original dataTable is imported from an Excel file, and when i inspect the elements while debugging, the values in the datatable are written correctly with '.' as separator for decimals. i even tried to save the output of   `row.Field<double?>(col)` to see what value does it have and it was evaluated correctly.  yet the error takes place in that line.

Comment: Decimals don't have any specific decimal separator, they are binary values. A separator is used *only* when they are converted to strings. The  output of `row.Field<double?>(col)` will be a `Nullable<double>` by definition, but concatenating it to a string will convert it to a string using the *current user's culture*. Use `String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"x=c(x, {0})" ,row.Field<double?>(col))` instead, or "x=c(x, " + row.Field<double?>(col).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ") "

Comment: I tried the second option and it works perfectly. thanks for clarifying things. would you post your comment as an answer to be marked so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-adding  @Panagiotis Kanavos proposition as an answer since it solves the problem-

Decimals don't have any specific decimal separator, they are binary values. A separator is used only when they are converted to strings. The output of `row.Field<double?>(col)` will be a `Nullable<double>` by definition, but concatenating it to a string will convert it to a string using the current user's culture.

Use `String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"x=c(x, {0})" ,row.Field<double?>(col))` instead, or `"x=c(x, " + row.Field<double?>(col).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ") "` –